# Managing contacts in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, abaddressbook, cncontactstore

I'm attempting to manage a hidden contact group or container in iOS using swift.

My initial thought was to create our own container, but I can't find code to do that. Can you create a container using CNContactStore or Address Book and mark it hidden?

My second thought was to create a group on the default container. I know I can create a group, but is there a way to mark it hidden so it won't appear in the contacts won't appear in their address book and clutter their personal contacts?

Comment: Hi there, did you find any solution which works for you?

Comment: @iRaviiVooda I have not, but I do still need an answer if you have found a way.